# Add enum to spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-webflow

I want to include an enum

```
public enum ContactType {
    PHONE,
    FAX,
    MAIL
}
```

to my `flow.xml` to have access in the views and also in the flow itself. I tried to add it as a var (like bean):

```
<var name="ContactType" class="my.package.common.util.ContactType"/>
```

But I get the error:

```
NoSuchMethodException: my.package.common.util.ContactType.<init>()
```

Should I `init()` the enum in some way? or maybe there is another way to include it?

Comment: Did you try http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/78197-enum-constants-in-webflow-expression-language??

Comment: which EL are you using? Spring EL? OGNL?

Comment: @rptmat57 Spring EL

Comment: might not be what you need or want, but if you want to use it in var you could use string instead

Comment: also if you switch var to input with type then it should work

Comment: @rptmat57 thanks for the idea, but I already has flow with strings comparison workin, but is ugly and not much maintainable... so I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to proceed this way. Not the best, but should work with your small enum set:

```
<evaluate expression="T(my.package.common.util.ContactType).PHONE" result="conversationScope.phoneContactType"/>
<evaluate expression="T(my.package.common.util.ContactType).FAX" result="conversationScope.faxContactType"/>
<evaluate expression="T(my.package.common.util.ContactType).MAIL" result="conversationScope.mailContactType"/>
```

Hopefully this works for you - else @rptmat57 solution above should be considered.

Reference: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/78197-enum-constants-in-webflow-expression-language

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as per [spring webflow docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/defining-flows.html#var-element):

> Use the var element to declare a flow variable:
>
> Make sure your variable's class implements java.io.Serializable, as the **instance** state is saved between flow requests.

Or

> Enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9

So...